# Starting out as a private tour guide in a large North American city, how can I find customers?

Tags: marketing, attracting-clients, growth, canada

I currently do IT consulting but would like to try working as a private tour guide. I live in Toronto, Canada, and have been here for most of my life.

I have a few bicycles, but no car. I do not own a [bicycle built for two](http://enwp.org/tandem_bicycle), but can rent one, and have experience in operating them. Perhaps environmentally-friendly downtown tandem tours could be my niche.

I speak English, plus a fair bit of Hebrew.

What are some good ways for me to find customers?

Should I post ads on Craigslist and Kijiji? Is it legal for me to solicit business in person, inside the Greyhound bus station or the train station? How about on the sidewalks just outside the stations? Should I create a sign?

What other advice can you offer me?

Comment: You might like to check out [Local Guiding](http://www.localguiding.com/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know about the legality of soliciting business at the bus or train station. But I think you are on the right track by thinking about:

- Who would purchase my services, and
- Where can I find those people

Some other suggestions:

- Connecting with the concierge service of some hotels that might get the customers interested in your service (probably not the ones catering to business travelers)
- Connecting with some hostels
- What about advertising with the local travel bureau? Or some group that purports to provide information to travelers?
- Is there a free local publication geared towards environmentally friendly consumers? We have one here in Minnesota that comes out monthly, and is available at many places. (Yoga studios, natural food stores, etc.) If there is something comparable in Toronto, that might be a good place to advertise.